# How to download latest version of cmake using tar xzf?

Tags: software-installation, tar, cmake

When I did cmake --version I got this -

```
cmake version 2.6-patch 4
```

Comment: Did you _just_ type `configure`?

Answer (score 3):

The compilation process from a (compressed) tar file normally consists of:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Where the first line often can have multiple options (like `--prefix=/usr` to install executables in `/usr/bin` instead of the more usual default `/usr/local/bin`). Running `configure` alone is never enough to install software from such a tar file.

However you should **always** look if there is a file called INSTALL* or README* and see if there are special instructions. For `cmake` there is a `README.rst` which tells you:

```
Building CMake from Scratch
---------------------------

UNIX/Mac OSX/MinGW/MSYS/Cygwin
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

You need to have a compiler and a make installed.
Run the ``bootstrap`` script you find the in the source directory of CMake.
You can use the ``--help`` option to see the supported options.
You may use the ``--prefix=<install_prefix>`` option to specify a custom
installation directory for CMake. You can run the ``bootstrap`` script from
within the CMake source directory or any other build directory of your
choice. Once this has finished successfully, run ``make`` and
``make install``.  In summary::

 $ ./bootstrap && make && make install
```

So you should follow the advice in the summary there.

Comment: If you're wondering what the three commands do: `configure` _sets up_ the environment based on the details of your computer (for instance, based on what libraries are present); `make` compiles the program; `sudo make install` puts the compiled binaries in the proper places.